# centos5 postgresql client

Tags: postgresql, client, centos5

How can I install postgresql client only in centos 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For PostgreSQL 8.4 client (recommended):

```
yum install postgresql84
```

For PostgreSQL 8.1 client:

```
yum install postgresql
```